# Gnome .. Using a flat screen vertically

Tags: display, gnome, gnome-terminal

I got a [L2440P 24" Wide Flat Panel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001J8D8P6) monitor.

This is a rectangular and I was thinking to mount it vertically to increase my vertical space rather than horizontal [I can read more lines of codes etc]. 
I am figuring out a way to do that on my gnome desktop [2.16.0]. I tried to access system=>pref=>resolution .. here the rotate option is not active for selecting. [Also I dont know if this option just rotates the screen blindly or it actually starts using a vertical display]

Has anyone tried this before ?. Any pointers guys ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using xrandr and see if that works: `xrandr -o left` and `xrandr -o normal` to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very generic answer because you don't give any relevant details in your question.

Screen rotation (by a quarter turn) is a well-known feature. Some screens even have sensors that report their orientation to the video card so that it rotates the display accordingly. Its support however depends on both the video card and the video drivers, so it is not always available and may have a cost (sometimes you have to choose between a rotated screen and decent display performance).

Gnome doesn't matter here, except in as much it gives you a dialog box where you can click on some settings. What matters is:

- your operating system (e.g. “Ubuntu 10.04”, “OpenBSD 4.7”);
- your exact video card model (if you don't know, `lspci | grep -i display` should give the relevant information);
- what video driver you are using (and whether you're willing to change if necessary). (Under Linux, you often have a choice between an open-source driver and a closed-source driver. Sometimes only one of them can do screen rotation, but it might be unable to do something else like 3D or dual head.)

To see if your current software configuration supports screen rotation, run `xrandr` with no parameters. If it prints a line like `DVI-0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 517mm x 323mm`, your system supports rotations and mirroring. If you see only `(normal)`, you're out of luck with your current driver version and hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already explain how to rotate the monitor, either by using `xrandr` or Gnome's display settings.

On thing you should be aware of: Many (most?) LCD monitors will have somewhat degraded image quality if you rotate them. They are designed to be viewed in their "normal" position, and at least the viewing angle will be worse when they are rotated. The [Wikipedia article on page orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_orientation#Rotation_of_CRT_monitors) explains this in more detail.

So you'll have to check whether you are still satisfied with the image quality of the rotated display. Otherwise you may have to pay for a display specifically designed to be rotated (they exist, but are probably more expensive).